# Client-directed sign-in in Azure Container Apps gives me IDX10205

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-container-apps

### Background

We have special needs for authentication when using Azure Container Apps as we're using an OpenID Connect provider were we have to add something to the query string for the initial redirect to the provider for the specific tenant logging in to our application. In addition, the IDP we use only supports the "authorization_code" flow and does not allow for both the "token" and the "id_token" to be returned.

With this we have started down the path of creating a sort of "middleware" that we use to redirect to that changes the URL and then just redirects to the actual IDP. For this to work we also then change the "redirect_uri" part to call back to this "middleware" with the "authorization_token".

When we get the callback we go back to the IDP and exchanges the **code** for the **id_token** and **access_token**.

We then wanted to use the [Client-directed sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/authentication#client-directed-sign-in) approach of Azure Container Apps to get an **authorization_token** that we can pass back in as the HTTP header **X-ZUMO-AUTH** as described in the docs.

Problem is that when go post to the container apps `.auth/login/<auth-provider-name>` we get an error back saying that issuer validation failed (IDX10205):

```json
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden]'."
}
```

Not sure what issuer it is expecting. The issuer coming out of the JWT is the one we're expecting, the one from the IDP.

Answer (score 0):

This was all me. And no one else :)

I had the brilliant idea of sanitizing the issuer URL when configuring the authentication provider and removed the trailing slash. Didn't like that, hurtful to the eyes :)

Putting it back and all of a sudden I'm getting the **authenticationToken**.

Stuck in a loop though, but that requires more investigation before I can potentially ask another question here.